# Sitecore commerce 9.3.0 (rev. 003498) sellable and catalog items not indexed in Solr 8.1.1

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce, indexing

We have created Catalog through Sitecore Commerce. This is working fine in UAT environment.

We are going to make Production Server same replication of UAT server.

We have exported Catalog from UAT server and imported into Production server. While building the “Sitecore_master_index” index catalog indexes are not getting created in Solr 8.1.1.

In UAT Catalog is having 2 versions for “en” language where in production Catalog is showing 2 versions of other languages.

1. How to build index in Solr.
2. Please let us know why the same number of versions showing for all languages in Production server.

[image: Languages list]